# some HKLM Registry Key Data is unavailable in c#

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I wondered if anyone else can verify that this is a "thing" it may be some obscure group policy dilemma / user permissions issue: I can find nothing online

I can't get to

`@\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate`

```
var r = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT");
if (r != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key exists");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key does not exist");
}
```

= `Key exists`

but

```
var r = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate");
if (r != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key exists");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key does not exist");
}
```

= `Key does not exist`

but they both exist in RegEdit

[image]

Comment: Regedit runs elevated. Try running your program elevated.

Comment: yeah I was hoping to not have to do that..

Comment: Keys are protected just like the filesystem is protected. The account using the application must have minimum rights to view a key in order to access it. You can assign those rights as an admin, but there's no getting around it.

Comment: are your code is 32bit on 64 bit windows ? if so - registry redirection. and you need check error returned - key not exist error or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry supports (much like the file system) per-key access permissions. They're not used very often on a real per-key level, but this seems to be one of those cases (can't verify it directly right now, as I don't see the difference in the permission dialog for these two folders)

Comment: I can confirm that `administrators` do not see this key either